# what to install cordova -g vs phonegap -g

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

I'm just starting with phonegap and I need to install CLI. But I'm confused as to which of the following two I should install (or both):

```
npm install -g phonegap
```

According to [main page](http://phonegap.com/install/) of phonegap.com

```
npm install -g cordova
```

According to [docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) of phonegap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use phonegap (`npm install -g phonegap`) if you want to use phonegap build service i.e build.phonegap.com.

If you want to use SDKs installed in your local environment(Local PC) to build hybrid apps you should be using the cordova option. i.e `npm install -g cordova`